# Issue rendering information from views.py django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-views

Having an issue rendering information on a form within the dashboard of my site, where it displays information the user entered at registration.

**The error message I am receiving is AttributeError at /dashboard/: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'profileuser'**

Any thoughts to what I am doing wrong?

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    user_title = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name="Influencer Level", blank=True)
    user_points = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name="Style Points", blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images/',null=True, blank=True)


    #admin level and additional infomation
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #Override the _unicode_() method to return out something meaningful
    def __unicode__(self):
        return ' %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.birthday, self.city, self.state, self.image, self.user_title, self.user_points)
```

**views.py:**

```
def dashboard(request):
    template_var={}
    if request.user.is_authenticated():




        first_name=request.user.first_name
        last_name=request.user.last_name
        email=request.user.email
        username=request.user.username
        user = User.objects.get(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email,username=username)

        birthday=request.profileuser.birthday
        city=request.profileuser.city
        state=request.profileuser.state
        title=request.profileuser.user_title
        points=request.profileuser.user_points
        image=request.profileuser.image

        profileuser = ProfileUser.objects.filter(birthday=birthday, city=city, state=state, title=title,points=points,
            image=image)


        #Template 
        template_var["first_name"]=first_name
        template_var["last_name"]=last_name
        template_var["email"]=email
        template_var["username"]=username
        template_var["birthday"]=birthday
        template_var["city"]=city
        template_var["state"]=state
        template_var["title"]=title
        template_var["points"]=points
        template_var["image"]=image

        template_var["is_authenticated"]= True
    return render_to_response("userprofile/dashboard.html",template_var, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Error message  here**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'home',
 'profiles',
 'south')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/Indieitude/profiles/views.py" in dashboard
  86.         birthday=request.profileuser.birthday

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dashboard/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'profileuser'
```

Comment: You'll get much better help if you tell us what "issue" is you have when trying to render it. Is there an error? What, exactly?

Comment: Just updated with my error!

Comment: @Amechi there is no `profileuser` in the `request` object. Show your `User` and `ProfileUser` model definitions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query your database for the User and assign it to variable `user`.

Then you start asking for information from the `profileuser` object in the request--but, obviously from the error, there's no object called `profileuser` in the request (and there normally wouldn't be one; standard Django will put an object called "user" in the request with the currently-logged in user, but it does't add anything called "profileuser".

- Your don't need to search your database for the user (your `user = User.objects.get(..)`). You already *have* the user as `request.user`.
- You *do* need to find the ProfileUser from your database. Is this a one-to-one related model? If so, you can get to it from the User by using the attribute name you used in your profile's `models.py`. This might be something like `profileuser = request.user.profile`. If you didn't set up ProfileUser as a one-to-related model, you could search for it with something like `profileuser = ProfileUser.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what the issue is about. Can you post any stack trace or more info regarding issue?

Anyway in pinpointing possible reason is it good practice to divide code into small parts and check which part is responsible for the issue.

In that case I would check if there is the issue with:

```
def dashboard(request):
    template_var={}
    if request.user.is_authenticated():

        first_name=request.user.first_name
        last_name=request.user.last_name
        email=request.user.email
        username=request.user.username

        return render_to_response("userprofile/dashboard.html",template_var, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```